# Derivative of product and summed function

Tags: derivatives

I am trying to take the derivative with respect to $x$ of the following function:

$$
F(x) = \sum_{i} ax^i(1-bx^j)\prod_k(1-cx^k)
$$

With $i\in [2,n]$, $j=n-i+1$ and $k=i+1$ to $n$.

I am struggling due to the product portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your sum as $$F(x)=a\sum_{i=2}^n\left\{\left(x^i-bx^{n+1}\right)\prod_{k=i+1}^n\left(1-cx^k\right)\right\}.$$As this is a sum of products, each of which [can be differentiated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation) using $$\left(\prod_h f_h(x)\right)^\prime=\left(\prod_h f_h(x)\right)\left(\sum_h\ln f_h(x)\right)^\prime=\left(\prod_h f_h(x)\right)\sum_h\frac{f_h^\prime(x)}{f_h(x)},$$we have$$F^\prime(x)=a\sum_{i=2}^n\left\{\left[\left(x^i-bx^{n+1}\right)\prod_{k=i+1}^n\left(1-cx^k\right)\right]\left(\frac{ix^{i-1}-(n+1)bx^n}{x^i-bx^{n+1}}-c\sum_{k=i+1}^n\frac{kx^{k-1}}{1-cx^k}\right)\right\}.$$I doubt this admits a nice further simplification.